# I am receiving an error while using hwc buildpack. My application uses .net framework 4.6.1

Tags: deployment, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

**cf push TOP-LEVEL-APP-NAME -s windows -b hwc_buildpack**
This is the command that I gave and below is the error that I receive
**Stack 'windows' was not found FAILED**

I am using manifest.yml and the exact same thing that is displayed [here][1]

Can anyone help me here?
[1]: https://dotnet-cookbook.cfapps.io/intro/getting_started/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Stack 'windows' was not found FAILED

This is telling you that the CF platform you have targeted does not have a stack called "windows". If you run `cf stacks` you can see a list of available stacks. It maybe that you're targeting an older CF platform that is using a different windows stack (older stacks had the year like 2016 or 2012r2 appended to the end of the stack name). You'll see in the output of `cf stacks` if the name is different. If that's the case, just update your `-s` argument for `cf push` and you should be all set.

It could also be that your Operations team just hasn't deployed Windows into this environment, so it's not available at all. If that's the case, you would need to talk with your Operations team and ask them to deploy Windows.